# Datetime parameter format from Crystal Reports to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a report using a SQL Server stored procedure that expects two `datetime` input parameters. However the stored procedure does not accept the input parameter value selected on prompt screen, generating an error

> 'Incorrect syntax near keyword CONVERT'.

SQL generated by report is using Convert function by default

```
EXECUTE [Projects_findings_summary_date]
     CONVERT (DATETIME, '12/01/2017 00:00:00', 120),
     CONVERT (DATETIME, '12/31/2017 12:59:59', 120) 
GO
```

This code generated the error in SQL Server Management Studio as well. But it works fine if we take the `CONVERT` function out.

```
EXECUTE [Projects_findings_summary_date]
     '12/01/2017 00:00:00',
     '12/31/2017 12:59:59'
GO
```

Any help resolving this issue is appreciated.

We have recently upgraded to Crystal Reports 2016 and SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use convert/cast functions when passing variables to the stored procedure, but you declare the variables before passing it to the proc, do the convert/cast to the variables and then pass the variable to the proc, something like this:

```
Declare  @FromDate  DATETIME = CONVERT (Datetime,'12/01/2017 00:00:00', 120)
       , @ToDate    DATETIME = CONVERT (Datetime,'12/31/2017 12:59:59', 120);

EXECUTE [Projects_findings_summary_date] @FromDate
                                       , @ToDate
GO
```

**Note**

When you are converting a string to `DateTime` value, the third parameter (Style) in `CONVERT` function is redundant, DateTime has no style, it uses its standard format (ticks) to store data in SQL Server.

Comment: I am using Crystal reports to read the SP. On connecting the report prompts for value to be selected from a calendar. On execution the report generates the code with CONVERT automatically and generates the error. The workaround I see is creating a string report level variable to pass the values to SP instead of direct user input

Comment: Your note is wrong. The third parameter (style) is telling SQL Server how to convert the string to datetime. It's true that datetime doesn't have a display format (or style), but the string representation of it does have a style. Omitting the style parameter may result with an error or worst - wrong date. Does 12/01/2017 mean January 12th or December 1st? Only by using the style parameter you can tell SQL Server which one is it, and in this case 120 is the wrong value. It should either be 101 or 103.

Answer (score 0):

IN Crystal Report as command type the following

```
declare @datefrom as datetime = {?datefrom}  -- parameter in CR
declare @dateto as datetime = {?dateto}  -- parameter in CR

EXECUTE [Projects_findings_summary_date] @datefrom, @dateto

--@datefrom and @dateto are datetime variables
```

You don't need to convert

Comment: The SP filters underlying data set based on a timestamp. End users require the ability to input time to see records at a certain point of time. For ex - get list of all today's transactions until 3 PM. We cannot remove the time element from the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by using SQL OLE DB Native Driver instead of Microsoft OLE DB provider for SQL Server. Convert is not being generated by Crystal report now.

Comment: you don't need to convert

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by following the below steps.

1.Installing "MS OLE DB Driver" from link [MSOLEDBDRIVER](https://www.microsoft.com/en-%20us/download/details.aspx?id=56730) .

2.In stored procedure, replace  "DateTime" with "Date" for input parameters.

3.In Crystal Report, make a new connection, select ->OLE DB->"Microsoft OLE DB Driver 
   for SQL" as provider. In "Advanced Information" tab, set "DataTypeCompatibility" = 
   80.